# Selecting points with MINIMUM distance of 10 km from vector line in country?

Tags: qgis, distance

I have a huge amount of points and some lines in my QGIS map.

I want to do a selection just of those points that are minimum 10 km far from the line.

Any idea?

I have no problem doing the opposite (points within 10 km of the line) using buffers - but that's not what i need.

Comment: Select the points within 10km (a buffer) then switch selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a buffer 10km from your lines, then either as @Micheal suggests select all the points that **intersect** the buffer (using the spatial query plugin) and then invert the selection. Or more directly select using **isDisjoint** (which is not intersects really).

Comment: I created a Buffer of 10 km around the line. Then I used the Spatial Query to create a new selection of villages inside of the buffer (Points -> Within> buffer). It works and now I have a new layer with villages within 10km from the line. The question is: How to switch the selection, I didn't really get it @Michael

Comment: look on the select by expression menu (little E/yellow square) and there is an operation - invert selection or if you open attribute table there is a half yellow/half white icon there too.

Comment: it will work on the "selected layer" ie the one that is highlighted in the layer list

Comment: I found the operation BUT the thing is that I have two layers: the original one with all the points (12 566 points) and the second one with just points within 10km distance from lines (962 points). When I click on the second layer and then invert selection, these points (962 points) dissapear, which is obvious I suppose. In any case I cannot see the points outside of 10km area from lines. A way to do could be: show me all the points (layer 1) minus villages within 10km from lines (layer 2). Is this possible somehow? @Michael

Comment: Finally I was successful :) I created a new Spatial Query where I put as Source features: All points layer; where the feature: is disjoint, reference features of: points within the 10km buffer.Then I right click on the layer All points -> Save as: Save only selected features. Thanx a lot for your help